# JSON.stringify gives me wrong json array

Tags: json, debugging, serialization, escaping

I have this code:

```
var sidebars = {};
var counter = 0;

// Loop through all already crated sidebars
$('.custom_dynamic_sidebars li').each(function(event) {
    sidebars[counter] = $(this).text();
    counter++;
});

var sidebars_string = JSON.stringify(sidebars);
```

but it gives me this string:

```
{\"0\":\"aa\",\"1\":\"bb\"}
```

Here is javascript which sends array to the server:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"/welit_2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",    
        type:'POST',
        data:'action=dynamic_sidebars&sidebars='+sidebars_string+'',

        success:function(results) {
            console.log(results);
        }
    });
```

does anyone know what am I doing wrong?
thx for your time

Comment: works for me. How to you conclude the `sidebars_string` looks like it does?

Comment: the problem is that I put this to ajax but when I write to the ajax funciton this:

`function dynamic_sidebars() {

 $foo = $_POST['sidebars'];
 $new = json_decode($foo);

 echo $new;

 die();
}
add_action("wp_ajax_dynamic_sidebars", "dynamic_sidebars");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_dynamic_sidebars", "dynamic_sidebars");`

so it displays nothing...

Comment: ah, so it is broken after the transport to the server. Can you post the javascript which send it to the server? Instead of a comment better edit your question - that is better with the formatting.

Comment: still looks ok for me, unfortunately. What happens if you try: ` $new = json_decode($foo);`

Comment: argh, I meant:  $new = json_decode($foo, true);`

Comment: the weird thing is that if I type this:
echo $_POST['sidebars'];
so it displays this:
{\"0\":\"aa\",\"1\":\"bb\"}

but when I echo this: 
 $new = json_decode($foo);
it displays an empty line

Comment: that is odd, I mean the first one, because it looks ok in my test setup (no `\ `, just `{"0":"aa","1":"bb"}`) the second one is explainable - no valid JSON, so it returns NULL. I give up. Anyone else?

Comment: So I found a solution If you run stripslashes() on the JSON string before you output it, it works fine :) But thx for your time and advices :)

Answer (score 0):

> So I found a solution If you run stripslashes() on the JSON string before you output it, it works fine